# How to listen to changes occur when modifying a geometry

Tags: openlayers

As shown in the code posted below, I want to listen to any changes occur when modifying a geometry.
The way I registered to the `change` event does not cause any changes to be listened to.

I would like to be able to modify a geometry by extending its lines by the mouse cursor, which consequently results in a larger or smaller area of the modified geometry

How can I correctly use `change` event?

**code**:

```
registerOnModifyChangesListener() {
    this.#modifyEvt.on('change', evt => this.#evtListenerOnModifyChanges(evt));
}
```

Comment: Modifying geometry how? With draw interaction? With set `.setCoordinates` method? Please edit your question with more code/details of how geometry is modified.

Comment: @TomazicM i would like to be able to modify a geometry by extending its lines by the mouse cursor

Comment: See OL example at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/modify-test.html.

Comment: @TomazicM thanks for the example you provided, but it does not show how the event 'change'  can be used on a referent of ModifyEvent. i know how to listen to 'modifystart' and 'modifyend', but i do not know how to listen to 'change', can you help me please

Comment: Please edit your question and add more relevant code of how you are modifying geometry.

Comment: @TomazicM i solved it as shown in my own answer to my question. would you please tell me what do you think please

Comment: If it works for you, then it's OK. There is not enough code in the question for me to have opinion about that.

Comment: @TomazicM morning, would you please help me solving this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78170981/event-listener-of-removefeature-does-not-get-executed-when-a-feature-is-removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by listening to the event `change` of a `feature`. i registered that event inside `.on('modifystart'`

**code**

```
registerOnModifyStartsListener() {
    this.#keyOnEvtModifyStarts = this.#modifyEvt.on('modifystart', evt => this.#evtListenerOnModifyStarts(evt));
}

#evtListenerOnModifyStarts = evt => {
    if (this.#featureRecentlyHovered != null) {
        const modifiedGeomOrder = this.#featureRecentlyHovered.get(DigitizePolygonConstants.CONST_DIGITIZED_FEATURE_PROPERTY_GEOM_ORDER.description);
        var features = this.listenToMapFeaturesReadersInstance().value.getVectorSource().getFeatures();
        features.forEach(feature => {
            if (feature.get(DigitizePolygonConstants.CONST_DIGITIZED_FEATURE_PROPERTY_GEOM_ORDER.description) == modifiedGeomOrder) {
                feature.on('change', evt => this.#evtListenerOnModifyGeomChange(evt, feature));
            }
        });
    } else {
        this.#msg = JSON.stringify({msg:WTFTag + 'evtListenerOnModifyStarts().', featureRecentlyHovered:this.#featureRecentlyHovered});
        console.error(this.#msg);
        throw new Error(this.#msg);
    }
};

#evtListenerOnModifyGeomChange = (evt, feature) => {
    const area = getArea(feature.getGeometry());
    //code should be placed here
    
};
```